# Read quantization tables from JPEG files

Tags: python, performance, image, http

I'm developing an application that will hide information inside the quantization tables of JPEG files. It's called [DQTsteg](https://github.com/iamrcr/DQTsteg), if you want to know more about what I'm attempting to do.

Right now I'm developing the most basic component of this system, which is the part that reads quantization tables from files. So it'd be a good thing if this code were as fast as it can possibly be, as it'll be a very frequent operation.

[Here's the whole code on GitHub,](https://github.com/iamrcr/DQTsteg/blob/master/QT_reader.py) fewer than 93 lines long.

I have noticed that sometimes urllib.requests sometimes are somewhat slow (above one second).

I've seen some people on Stack Overflow saying that some servers don't support byte by byte requests through `urllib.request` (you either download the whole file or you don't). I don't know whether these people are right or not, but is there any case where this `urllib.request` could go wrong (and then I'd either be denied access to the target file or I'd loop endlessly over the first few bytes, or anything of this sort)?

Any suggestions are welcome. Here follows the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
QT_reader.py

Functions for reading quantization tables from files and URLs.

Below are some global variables defined according to the JPEG Standard.

"""

DEFINE_QUANTIZATION_TABLE = b'\xff\xdb'
SINGLE_TABLE_PAYLOAD_DATA = b'\x00\x43'
DOUBLE_TABLE_PAYLOAD_DATA = b'\x00\x84'

def load_file(jpgpath):
    """
    Loads a file from jpgpath. Direct acess not intended; use QT_get_single() or QT_get_all().
    Args:
        jpgpath (str): file path.
    Returns:
        jpgpath (object): file object.
    """
    if load_file.status == "web":
        import urllib.request
        jpgpath = urllib.request.urlopen(jpgpath)
    if load_file.status == "file":
        jpgpath = open(jpgpath,"rb")
    return jpgpath


def QT_get_single(jpgpath, status="file"):
    """
    Reads a single quantization table from file.
    Args:
        jpgpath (str): file path, local or URL.
        status (str): set to "file" for local files or set to "web" for URLs.
    Returns:
        tuple: A tuple with .tell() position for the DQT on [0] and the QT table itself on [1] as a bytearray.
    """
    if QT_get_single.status != "off":
        if status == "web":
            load_file.status = "web"
        elif status == "file":
            load_file.status = "file"
        load_file.jpgpath = jpgpath
        jpgpath = load_file(load_file.jpgpath)
    while True:
        while True:
            QT_buffer = jpgpath.read(2)
            if QT_buffer == DEFINE_QUANTIZATION_TABLE: break
            if QT_buffer == b'':
                raise EOFError("Reached end of file.")
        DQT_position = jpgpath.tell()
        QT_buffer = jpgpath.read(2)
        if QT_buffer == DOUBLE_TABLE_PAYLOAD_DATA:
            QT_buffer = jpgpath.read(130)
            break
        elif QT_buffer == SINGLE_TABLE_PAYLOAD_DATA:
            QT_buffer = jpgpath.read(65)
            break
        else:
            continue
    return ( DQT_position, bytearray(QT_buffer) )

def QT_get_all(jpgpath, status="file",stop=-1):
    """
    Reads multiple quantization tables from file. Reads all QTs by default.
    Args:
        jpgpath (str): file path, local or URL.
        status (str): set to "file" for local files or set to "web" for URLs.
        stop (int): Stop after retrieving the nth table. One retrieves one; two retrieves two; zero or default retrieves all.
    Returns:
        list: A list of QT_get_single() tuples.
    """
    QT_tables = []
    counter = 0

    load_file.status = status
    load_file.jpgpath = jpgpath
    jpgpath = load_file(load_file.jpgpath)

    QT_get_single.jpgpath = jpgpath
    QT_get_single.status = "off"

    while True:
        try:
            QT_buffer = QT_get_single(QT_get_single.jpgpath,QT_get_single.status)
            QT_tables.append(QT_buffer)
            counter += 1
        except: break
        if counter == stop: break
    return QT_tables
```

Comment: It might be worth while doing `from urrlib import request` rather than `import urrlib.request` because it will probably make the other bit look nicer as you just have to call `request...` rather than `urrlib.request...`

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but the link to your GitHub no longer works so we can't access the full program (including the imports, which would be valuable during review).

Comment: I'm sorry. As you've already said, this is an old question, and I no longer have access to the code. But I believe I didn't go much further than the code you're seeing attached to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I'm not very happy with this bit of documentation:

> Direct [access] not intended;

The community feels that the appropriate way to
convey such a "private" intention is with an `_` underscore, so:

```
def load_file(jpgpath):
```

becomes

```
def _load_file(jpgpath):
```

You mention `load_file.status`.
Based on the posted question, I have no idea what `load_file` is all about.
In particular, I do not see a relevant `import` statement.
Is there some unfamiliar idiom you'd like to clue the reviewer in to?
Where we tack on attributes to a function object?
Maybe we do that in some languages, but in python it
certainly is not a common idiom.

---

I am reading this signature:

```
def QT_get_single(jpgpath, status="file"):
```

Please stick to conventional identifiers.
[PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
asks that you name it `qt_get_single`.

---

I am reading this:

```
    while True:
        while True:
            QT_buffer = jpgpath.read(2)
            ...
```

and I have a lot of trouble with it.

Maybe that is the true spec for that file type?
But I have a hard time believing that.
At a minimum, please turn the infinite loop
into a bounded loop.

The `65` and `130` are
[magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).
Please handle them more gracefully,
perhaps with MANIFEST_CONSTANTS.

---

I am reading `QT_get_all`.
Ok, now I see where those fn.attr settings came from.
I feel that is a crazy convention to adopt.
Perhaps you will choose to turn functions
into `class` methods and convert them to `self.attr` variables.